# pl / postgres filter in multidimensional arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I have a table similar to this:

```
id | name | scores
---|------|-------
1  | dit  | {{3,145},{7,888},{6,13}}
2  | dat  | {{7,6}}
3  | dut  | {{2,3},{8,1}}
4  | dot  | {{7,2},{8,9}}
```

And I want each row in which scores exists an element that has a 7 as first integer and an integer greater than 4 as its second value.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE scores @> '{7,x}' AND x > 4
```

So the output would be:

```
id
--
1
2
```

With the help of jsonb I was able to find specific matches in scores but I can't find a way to use an variable and compare it to a value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? Is it a String comparison?

Comment: just added an answer using a small function

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following table structure ...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (id INT, scores NUMERIC[][]);
```

... containing the following records ...

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'{{3,145},{7,888},{6,13}}');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2,'{{7,6}}');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3,'{{2,3},{8,1}}');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4,'{{7,2},{8,9}}');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5,'{{7,5},{8,1}}');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (6,'{{2,1},{7,1}}');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (7,'{{7,3},{7,500}}');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (8,'{{7,1},{7,2}}');
```

... executing this function ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tom_function() RETURNS INT[] AS $$
DECLARE
 i RECORD;
 j INT;
 res INT[];
BEGIN
  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM t LOOP
    FOR j IN 1 .. ARRAY_LENGTH(i.scores, 1) LOOP
      IF i.scores[j][1]::INT = 7 AND i.scores[j][2]::INT > 4 THEN
         res := res || i.id;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
 RETURN res;
END $$ language plpgsql;
```

... should give you this resultset:

```
SELECT tom_function();


 tom_function 
--------------
 {1,2,5,7}
```

Or ..

```
SELECT UNNEST(tom_function());


 unnest 
--------
      1
      2
      5
      7
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks Jim for the precise answer. Very helpful!

Comment: This checks the if the dimension of the second value. That means (5,'{{7,5},{8,1}}'); would be excluded. Am I right?